# Spoofing an IP/MAC address to avoid ICMP Destination Unreachable being sent back

Tags: spoofing, udp, flooding, icmp, lan

As far as I understand UDP flooding the idea is to send UDP packets across all ports from e.g. Alice to Bob, and get Bob's machine to check who listens to certain ports and generate many ICMP destination unreachable packets to be sent back (+ Bob's machine gets less responsive to other clients running on his machine).

However, wouldn't all of these ICMP destination unreachable packets also cause trouble for Alice?

So I guess my question would be, is it possible to perform a UDP flood on a local network where packets sent from Alice to Bob across all ports would be transmitted to Bob, but all ICMP destination unreachable packets would not be bounced back to Alice (since IP/MAC address in the UDP packets would be altered)?
Additionally, would this reduce bandwith for the whole local network (e.g. slowing down Alice's internet speed)?